request axios in a queue
I am making request posts with axios for a form that has several steps.
So in step one I post once, then in step two I post a second time, and like x time.
Problem if there is an internet bug and the first request does not go through so the order will be request 2 and then 1 whereas I would absolutely like it to be in order, so I think there needs to be a queue, I was thinking of P-queue.
Is it possible to integrate it into axios or do you have another method?
i use axios and vue.js 3

queue.add will add a promise into the queue, set concurrency to 1, it will execute one by one
const axiosRequestFunction = async () => {
  await axios.post()......// do what ever request you want
}

const queue = new PQueue({ concurrency: 1 })

queue.add(() => axiosRequestFunction1(params1))
queue.add(() => axiosRequestFunction2(params2))
queue.add(() => axiosRequestFunction3(params3))

